# Can I change file metadata with Deno?

Tags: deno

From the [docs](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.stat) it looks like you can use 'stat' to read file metadata (like mtime, atime, size etc.) but not set it. I would like to change the last-modified date, plus the created date on Windows.

Is that possible with Deno yet? Or will I have to shell out and use OS native tools to do it?

Comment: Deno doesn't have this yet. If it were me, I'd create a function that takes your arguments and passes them to `Deno.run` to do it via a PowerShell command (since you said it's for Windows). Then you can parse the output and return whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks @jsejcksn, I ended up doing it in Python as the date manipulation stuff was 90% of the point of the program anyway. I was just looking for an excuse to use Deno really!